# REST API URI for entities with two different keys

Tags: rest, api, data-modeling

I must design an API to manage a Document entity: the originality of this entity is it can have two different ids:

- id1 (number, i.e. 1234)
- id2 (number, i.e. 89)

For each document, one and only one id is available (id1 or id2, not both)

Usually I solve this issue by using query parameters to perform some kind of "search" feature:

```
GET /documents?id1=1234
GET /documents?id2=89
```

But it works only if there is no sub-entity...

Let's say I want to get the authors of the documents :

```
GET /documents/1234/authors
```

Impossible because I can't know what type of id I get: is it id1 or id2 ?

```
GET /documents/authors?id1=1234
```

Not really REST I think because id1 then refers to the "Author" entity, not "Document" anymore...

```
GET /id1-documents/1234/authors
GET /id2-documents/1234/authors
```

Then you create two URIs that return the same entity (/author) not really REST compliant.

```
GET /documents/id1=1234/authors
GET /documents/id2=89/authors
```

It looks like a composite key created only for the API, it has no "backend" meaning. For me it sounds strange to create a "composite" key on the fly.

```
GET /document-authors?id1=1234
GET /document-authors?id2=89
```

In this case you completely lose the notion of tree... You end up with an API that contains only root entities.

Do you see another alternative ?
Which one looks the best ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the two different types of ids? In your example, they both just look like int's so does that mean you can have two different documents with id '89' but that one document has id1 89 and the other has id2 89? Or are the ids orthogonal / non-overlapping in some way?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Both IDs are integer, no restriction. But if id1 is defined, id2 isn't and reciprocally. And yes you can have two different documents with id '89' but that one document has id1 89 and the other has id2 89.

Comment: The devil is in the details. URIs like that look and feel easy and natural, but when you need to account for say a "/" in data in the field on which you filter the implementation gets more complex. Query string approach is easier in this but does not look nearly as clean imho.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear for me which proposition is the best for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're conflating two different resources here - `documents` and `authors`. A `document` has a relationship with an `author`, but they should be separate resources because the `author`s have existence from any individual document. With that in mind you need to ask whether your clients are searching for authors or documents. If it's authors, then they should be querying an authors API rather than a documents API.

e.g.For all the authors of documents with id1 89 or id1 1234 or id2 4444 you might query like this...

`GET /authors?docId1=89&docId1=1234&docId2=4444`

That should return a list of author representations. If people care about the documents themselves, the author representations could contain links to the documents.

Alternatively, if you're looking for `documents` then you should be querying that directly...

`GET /documents?id1=89&id1=1234&id2=4444`

What you're modelling as a sub-resource isn't *really* a subresource. It's a relationship between 2 independent resources and should be modelled as a set of links. Each document returned from the `documents` api should contain a set of `authors` links (if people really care about the authors) and vice versa from the authors to the documents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed Author isn't really a sub-resource, it's a bad example. Let's say Document has a sub-resource called "Signatures" or "Metadata", then it's true sub-resources. How should I design that? Thanks

Comment: You just need to structure your URIs so that the two types of identifier are distinct, e.g. `/documents/id1Type/89` , `/documents/id2Type/12345`. Then each document has a unique URI and the sub-resource lives under the well-defined document URI (`/documents/id1Type/89/signatures`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed it may be a solution: I saw this possibility many times on stackoverflow. But isn't it a problem id1Type isn't really an entity, a true object? And if I implement this, I'll end up with two routes : GET /documents/id2Type/{id}/signatures and GET /documents/id1Type/{id}/signatures. 2 URIs return the same resource, no? Thanks again

Comment: According to your description of the id types any document can have only one id, with that being one of the 2 id types, but the id's overlap so you need a means to differentiate them. By naming the id type in the path you allow for the document to be returned if it exists for that id, otherwise a 404 - so URI semantics are safe. Searches should go to the top-level `/documents` resource so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Also, notionally `/documents/idtype1` *could* be a resource - it could return all documents for just that id type, it could be for creating documents of that id type. A resource is not the same thing as an entity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an opinionated solution from SlashDB, which allows for record filtering and traversing to related resources at the same time.

The example is similar to yours - two entities Artist and Album.

Let's identify the Artist first.

Artist by ID:

https://demo.slashdb.com/db/Chinook/Artist/ArtistId/2

Artist by Name:

https://demo.slashdb.com/db/Chinook/Artist/Name/Accept

An Artist may have issued Albums. The two entities are related. We allow extending the URL with the name of the related entity, like so:

https://demo.slashdb.com/db/Chinook/Artist/Name/Accept/Album

You can keep "going", say to get to the Tracks from those albums

https://demo.slashdb.com/db/Chinook/Artist/Name/Accept/Album/Track

And even continue filtering too i.e. only tracks, which are shorter than 300000 milliseconds:

https://demo.slashdb.com/db/Chinook/Artist/Name/Accept/Album/Track/Milliseconds/..300000

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It really looks like @sisyphus solution, so I guess if many sources agree on the solution, that's definitely interesting ;)